# VirtManager, guest pause/save->resume, cannot RDP into guest

Tags: qemu, linux-kvm, virt-manager

If relevant, the guest is using "Macvtap device" as the "Network source". It seems that if I apply "pause" or "save" on the Windows guest, and then resume it, I cannot connect to the guest using RDP (if relavant, Remmmina).

The workaround I have found is unchecking the Link State: active, click apply, and then check it again, and then click apply. But this is cumbersome. Is there a better way to restore guest network than that?

[image]